# "Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow" error upon MySQLConnection.Open()

Tags: .net, mysql

Setup:

Windows 7 SP1 64 bit
Visual Studio 2012
MySQL .Net Connector 6.6.4

I have a vb .net WinForm app which connects to a MySQL server using the MySQL .Net Connector. It was working perfectly. I then formatted the pc, reinstalled the same version of windows as before, but I installed a slightly newer version of the MySQL .Net Connector, as well as Visual Studio 2012 instead of 2010.

When the code where I open the connection executes, i.e.:

```
Dim mySQLcon As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection("SERVER=www.tadirect.co.za;DATABASE=tadirq_db1;UID=********;PASSWORD=********;")
mySQLcon.Open()
```

At the mySQLcon.Open() line I get the following exception:

```
System.OverflowException: Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Authentication.MySqlAuthenticationPlugin.HandleAuthChange(MySqlPacket packet)
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Authentication.MySqlAuthenticationPlugin.Authenticate(Boolean reset)
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Authenticate(String authMethod, Boolean reset)
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open() at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver() at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection()
at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
at TAD_Automator.modWebsite.UpdateMySQLDatabase_Cases(Boolean bSilent)}
```

I have tried changing the build from Any CPU to 32 bit as well as 64 bit but it made no difference...

Any ideas? It used to work before I reinstalled Windows/VS/MySQL...

Comment: try to write your question simple and precise..too lengthy will annoy the people

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. Install MySQL connector 6.1.6 and you will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I believe MySQL dropped support for the old style of password encryption that they were using prior to 6.6.  I had the same problem and I had to turn off the old_password support on my DB Server and then recreate the user so that the new password function is used to hash the password.

Check out this bug thread:  http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=67953

Check out this link for more information:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/old-client.html

Being a novice at this, it was easier for me to delete the user in question, change the DB options to turn off old_password encryption and authentication using MySQL Workbench, restart the DB Server, then recreate the user.  This solved the problem for me.  Hope this helps you - good luck.

Comment: You don't need to delete the user. Just reset the password from a client that can still login with the old one (after turning off the option, of course).